# MySQL count values and get the percentage in one sql-query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables containing information on employees and departments. Both look as follows

Employee table:

```
   ID_emp  ID_dep    year
    3000    4         0
    3001    4         1
    3002    4         2
    3003    16        3
    3004    15        3
```

Department table:

```
ID_dep    dep_descr
16       management
4        accounting
```

Now I need to find out the number of employees per department that are employed for more than 1 year and also provide the percentage number of employees in each department relative to the total number of employees that are employed for more than 1 year in the entire company (all departments).

The result should look something like this:

```
dep_descr   number of employees    percent of total employees
management          12                         5%
accounting          4                         1.6%
...                ...                        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
select 
    concat(cast(count(e.id_emp)/(select count(id_emp) from employee) * 100 as decimal(4,2)), '%') employees_in_dept, d.dep_descr
from employee e
inner join department d
on e.id_dep = d.id_dep
group by d.id_dep
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create temp table emp (id_emp int, id_dep int, nyear int);
create temp table dep (id_dep int, desc_dep text);
insert into dep values (16,'management'),(4, 'accounting');
insert into emp values (3000,4,0),(3001,4,1),(3002,4,2),(3003,16,3),(3004,16,3);

with cte (id_dep, desc_dep, num_employees) as
(
select emp.id_dep, dep.desc_dep, count(*)
from emp
    left join dep on emp.id_dep = dep.id_dep
where emp.nyear > 1
group by emp.id_dep, dep.desc_dep
)
select 
    cte.id_dep, 
    cte.desc_dep, 
    cte.num_employees, 
    cte.num_employees * 100 / (select count(*) from emp where emp.nyear > 1)::float as percent_of_total 
from cte;
```

Answer (score -1):

What have you tried so far? You may need to use a subquery to the total number of employees and use it to divide to the number of employees grouped by the department.

Comment: I have tried using count() together with groupby(). I manage to get to the point where I have a table that shows me the number of employees per department, however every attempt to include the percentage value results in an error :S